# Android - How to add a Google Map to this fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

I want to add a simple GoogleMap to this fragment.

```
package se.adrianhansson.runpoint;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private Button buttonStart;
    private View view;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        buttonStart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonHomeStart);
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    //public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    public void onButtonPressed(String string){
        if (mListener != null) {
            //mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            mListener.onFragmentInteractionHome(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    //no more use??
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteractionHome("Clicked");
//        switch (v.getId()) {
//            case R.id.buttonHomeStart:
//                mListener.onFragmentInteractionHome("Clicked start");
//                break;
//        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteractionHome(String string);
    }
}
```

**And here is my xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="se.adrianhansson.runpoint.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/buttonHomeStart"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried a million different ways. I have followed tutorials, tried to copy and modify my own code (which I ported over from an Activity, but apparently this doesn't work the same i fragments). I get a variety of errors and my app always crashes on all my attempts, no matter what I try.
So here is attached a "clean slate" of my fragment. Now.. how to add a google map to this?

So I hope that someone here can help me. How do I add a simple Google Map as "background" in my fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you have activated the Maps API and acquired a key from the Developer console, add a MapView to your current fragment  layout:

`<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

then make sure your Fragment implements this callback:

```
implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

declare a global `private MapView mapView;`

and a global GoogleMap if you need one `private GoogleMap mMap;`

then in the onCreateView of your fragment:

        `mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);`

and also implement the method for the callback:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86); // Perth, Australia
    Marker mymarker = googleMap.addMarker(new  MarkerOptions().position(PERTH).title("Perth,Australia"));
    mymarker.showInfoWindow();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PERTH, 16));
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! The map is up in the background with no crashes now. HOWEVER, it seems to load really slow and I can't seem to scroll or zoom or interact with it (other than clicking on the red marker ("Peth, Australia"), which does toggle display the marker name).

Comment: Edit: Though I seem to be able to double tap to zoom in. But no other controls work.

Comment: Since I'm using a GoogleMap differently - in an Activity - I cannot help you any further. I simply found the solution for you and it is to use a `MapView` instead if you are working with a `fragment`. When I tried the solution before giving it to you, the map was slow indeed. I suggest that you read around about `MapView` if no one else comes around to give a suggestion.

Comment: Well this was as close as I got. Not exactly what I was looking for, but answer still provides a slightly alternate way to do it.